# Переменная для изменения градиента

Tags: html, css, градиент

Можно ли используя переменную изменить количество blue (тут 85%)? Т.е. я передаю в переменную число и количество синего меняется. Если да, то как?

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, blue 85%, white 10%);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Переменные в CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

```js
size.oninput = () => {
  let val = size.value;
  el.style = `--color-size: ${val}%`;
}

size.oninput();
```

```css
div{
  --color-size: 80%; /* значение поумолчанию */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue var(--color-size), white 10%);
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.half {
  --color-size: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div class="half"></div>

<div id="el"></div>

<input id="size" value="85" type="number">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const elem = document.documentElement;
const range = document.querySelector(".range");
const text = document.querySelector(".text");




range.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  let val = event.target.value;

  text.textContent = `You like ${val}`;

  elem.style.setProperty('--color-proc', `${val}%`);

});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

:root {
    --color-proc: 85%;
}

.a{
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue var(--color-proc), white 10%);
}

.text{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<input class="range" type="range" max='90' step='1' value='85'>
<p class="text">You like 85</p>
```

Можно так